# getting :before :after pseudo classes to work with links on images

Tags: jquery, css, image, css-selectors, hover

I have multiple images on my page and I want them to have a dark overlay over them (like a black rectangle with .6 opacity) that disappears with a hover. That's the easy part.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.item:after,
.item:before {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
}
.item:after {
  content: '\A';
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.item:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 1;
  padding: 34px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:hover:after,
.item:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-content="Image Title">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x267">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="item" data-content="Second Image Title">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x267">
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cLcmhuzo/)** with the overlay working but is not responsive on mobile.

**Here's my problem:** I want the images to be linked as well. Which doesn't seem to be compatible with the :before :after pseudo classes. I've tried replacing

```
content: '\A';
```

with

```
{ content: ' [' attr(href) ']'; }
```

But with no luck. The images do turn to links, but they do not have the overlay anymore. They are also not responsive on mobile How can I fix this? Here's a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7q7dnzxr/)** with the links working but no overlay.

**How can I have an image with an over lay that disappears on hover and turns to a link But is also mobile responsive? Possibly some jquery?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` in your pseudo-elements.

For responsive images you can add the following properties:

- `max-width: 100%;`
- `height: auto;`
- `display: block;`

**Note:** Make sure the properties with vendor prefixes always precede the unprefixed one.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.item:after,
.item:before {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.item:after {
  content: '\A';
 width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.item:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 1;
  padding: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:hover:after,
.item:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-content="First image Title">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x267">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item" data-content="Second Image Title">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180x267">
  </a>
</div>
```

---

- [`pointer-events` property summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) - source *MDN*.
- [`pointer-events` browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) - source *Can I Use*.

Comment: This gets the links to work! thank you. What I meant with responsive images isn't my images themselves. I know how to make them responsive. But, the overlay will not scale with the images. Even if you run your snippet, if you resize the browser, the overlay won't stay on the image.

Comment: @jburnit Oh I see, in my browser it does always fit, but the problem is that you need to specify `top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` in your overlay. This way you can remove the `width` and `height` from it and it will always cover the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the `:before` and `:after` effects on the links instead of parent containers?

https://jsfiddle.net/cLcmhuzo/1/

I'm not sure I understand the part about making it mobile responsive. What have you tried? What part isn't working? Seems that just changing the widths from a fixed pixel size to a percentage would work fine.